# TSQL GROUP BY without aggregating

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Consider the following two tables:

```
key_names
----------------------------------------------
id | name
----------------------------------------------
1    Outside Temperature
2    Inside Temperature
3    Relative Humidity 

key_values
----------------------------------------------
id | time                    | key_id | value
----------------------------------------------
1    2013-06-04 13:20:16.347   1        50
2    2013-06-04 13:20:16.348   2        30
3    2013-06-04 13:20:16.349   3        10
4    2013-06-04 13:20:31.120   1        55
5    2013-06-04 13:20:31.122   2        29
6    2013-06-04 13:20:31.120   3        11
```

Values are written to the database at 15 second intervals for 3 different keys. I want to be able to pull out values at 1 minute, 5 minute, 1 hour, and other intervals.

This is what I have right now for a five minute interval:

```
SELECT time, key_name, value
FROM key_values kv
JOIN key_names kn ON kv.key_id = kn.id
WHERE (key_id = 1 OR key_id = 2 OR key_id = 3)
    AND time >= '2013-06-04 12:20:30' 
    AND time < '2013-06-04 13:20:30'
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, time), DATEPART(MONTH, time), DATEPART(DAY, time),
    DATEPART(HOUR, time), (DATEPART(MINUTE, time) / 5), kv.key_id, kn.key_name
ORDER BY kv.time DESC
```

Of course, this query is going to give me the following error:

> Column 'key_values.time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But I don't want any aggregate data! I just want the actual values for the rows at the five minute interval. How can I fix this query?

Expected Result Set: (for 5 minute interval)

```
----------------------------------------------------
time                | key_id | value
----------------------------------------------------
2013-06-04 13:20:16   1        50
2013-06-04 13:20:16   2        30
2013-06-04 13:20:16   3        10
2013-06-04 13:15:16   1        ...
2013-06-04 13:15:16   2        ...
2013-06-04 13:15:16   3        ...
2013-06-04 13:10:16   1        ...
2013-06-04 13:10:16   2        ...
2013-06-04 13:10:16   3        ...
...                   ...      ...
```

---

For one of the guys answering my question:

```
SELECT time, key_name, value
FROM (
        SELECT time, key_name, value, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by convert(varchar(16), time, 121) order by time desc) as seqnum
        FROM key_values kv
        JOIN key_names kn ON kn.id = kv.tag_id
        WHERE (key_id = 1 OR key_id = 2 )
                AND time >= '2013-06-04 12:20:30' AND time < '2013-06-04 13:20:30'
) k
where seqnum = 1;


Its only returning one of the keys..

2013-06-04 12:20:59.577 Outside Temperature     45
2013-06-04 12:21:59.607 Outside Temperature     45
2013-06-04 12:22:59.637 Outside Temperature     45
2013-06-04 12:23:59.687 Outside Temperature     45
2013-06-04 12:24:59.697 Outside Temperature     46
2013-06-04 12:25:59.723 Outside Temperature     46
```

Comment: Well, can you show what you actually want as output?

Comment: Okay. I added the expected result set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the `row_number()` function to enumerate values in each interval.  Then, just take the last one or the first one -- depending on whether you want the last just before the interval or the first before it.

Here is an example for the 1-minute interval:

```
select time, key_name, value
from (SELECT time, key_name, value,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by key_name, convert(varchar(16), time, 121) order by time desc) as seqnum
      FROM key_values kv join
           key_names kn
           ON kv.key_id = kn.id
     ) k
where seqnum = 1;
```

The expression `convert(varchar(16), time, 121)` is formatting the date to the nearest minute (using truncation).

EDIT:
Other increment.  The following example show how to do this for spans of 15 minutes:

```
(partition by key_name, datediff(minute, 0, time)/15 order by . . . )
```

For 5 minute increments use `5` instead of `15` and so on.  This is calculating the number of minutes since the beginning of time (database-ly speaking).  SQL Server does integer division, so dividing by the integer creates an identifier for the time span.  For other units, you can replace the `minute` with `hour`, `second`, `day`, `month`, or `year`.

For the original query, I figured that `convert()` was easier to understand.

Comment: Lots of new keywords and functions to learn about in this answer. I like! It's not quite working as I would expect it to, please see this pastie: http://pastebin.com/X2X6ShAB

Comment: @ChrisG. . . . That site is actually blocked where I am; can you describe the problem or paste it in your question?

Comment: @ChrisG. . . That is easily fixed.  It was getting only one record in each time slice instead of one record per key.  The fix was to add `key_name` into the `partition` clause.

Comment: I see how varchar(16) is truncating the datetime to the nearest minute, but I'm not sure how to modify this query to get the nearest 5 minutes, 15 minutes, or 30 minutes. `convert()` isn't going to give me that much control, is it?